# Filling a 3D Array and Plotting the Values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, colormap

I would like to write a code in Python that evaluates the time evolution of a density distribution, p(x,y). The initial conditions is p(t=0,x,y)=exp[-((x-500)^2)/500] and the formula for the solution is in the code below: t-time index, i-space index (x-direction), j-space index (y-direction), and v=0.8

My goal is to run the scheme for 10 iterations and plot the results at the final time step (t=9). What I'm getting is a big array just filled with zeros. I think it's because I am not using the 3D arrays correctly, does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

**My attempt:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Input Parameters
Nx = 1000 #number of grid points in x-direction
Ny = 500 #number of grid points in y-direction
T = 10 #number of time steps
v = 0.8

p = np.zeros((T,Nx,Ny))
P = np.zeros((T,Nx,Ny))

for t in range(0,T-1):
    for i in range(0,Nx-1):
        for j in range(0,Ny-1):
            P[t,i,j] = p[t,i,j]-((v/2)*(p[t,i+1,j]-p[t,i,j]))
            p[0,i,j] = np.exp(((-1*(i-500))**2)/500)


x = P[9,i]
y = P[9,j]
print(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim([0,1000]) 
plt.ylim([0,500]) 
plt.xlabel('x-direction')
plt.ylabel('y-direction')
plt.title("Density Distribution After 10 Iterations")
```

Comment: Are you sure your formula is correct? `p[t,i,j]-((v/2)*(p[t,i+1,j]-p[t,i,j]))` is always 0 and `np.exp(((-1*(i-500))**2)/500)` is extremely large

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing this out. I tried to simplify the formula for the purpose of asking the question, because the actual formula is very long. The initial condition np.exp(((-1*(i-500))**2)/500) should represent a narrow vertical pulse (max value = 1, min value = 0) centered at x=500. For reference, the true formula is the Lax-Wendroff solution of the 2D advection equation: P[t,i,j] = p[t,i,j]-((v/2)*(p[t,i,j+1]-p[t,i,j]))-((v/2)*(p[t,i+1,j]-p[t,i,j]))+(((v**2)/2)*(p[t,i,j+1]-(2*p[t,i,j])+p[t,i,j-1]))+(((v**2)/2)*(p[t,i+1,j]-(2*p[t,i,j])+p[t,i-1,j]))

Comment: so I can just replace them with dummy constant numbers and see if the rest is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: Try to comment your code. There seem to be mistakes in indexing. Some mistakes I notice are 1) `p[0, i, j]` why 0? should be t logically speaking 2) `p[0,i,j] = np.exp(((-1*(i-500))**2)/500)` this expression should come before the other 3) `P` is a 3D array, and the way you are picking x, y i.e. `x = P[9, i] and y = P[9, j]` doesn't seem correct 4) `range(0, T-1)` means range(0,9) and you never reach 9 so P[9,...] will be definitely zero

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only fill the values `for t in range(0,T-1)` which stops at T=8, and you are trying to get `x = P[9,i]`. They never get filled so obviously they are all 0.

Try to use `range(0, T)`, it will loop over `0,1,2,...,T-1`. Also change `range(0,Nx), range(0,Ny)`